# Passing variable to nested components after it has been set

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm passing a from and a json to components in my tab-group. My problem is that the html is created before I fetch the json from my server and the components end up with an undefined variable.

I've tried making the json a BehaviourSubject but the component just gives me error: Cannot read subscribe of undefined.
If just a normal var being passed it will be undefined too because it hasn't been set yet when it's passed to he component.

How do I solve this the most clean and efficient way?

Here is how I declare my BehaviorSubject:

```
public pcpConfig: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
```

Here is my tab group:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="Init Json"><app-init-json [eftForm]="configForm" [pcpConfig]="pcpConfig"></app-init-json></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Basic Parameters"><app-basic-parameters [eftForm]="configForm" [pcpConfig]="pcpConfig"></app-basic-parameters></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Aid list"><app-aid-list [tidId]="tidId"></app-aid-list></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Public keys"><app-public-keys [eftForm]="configForm"></app-public-keys></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

And then I fetch the json and set the value for the BehaviorSubject

```
this.pcpConfig.next(config);
```

I have also tried (adding ngIf to the mat group so it doesn't load before the pcpConfig):

```
public pcpConfig: PayAppInitFileDTO;
// after fetching the json I assing it to pcpCongfig
this.pcpConfig = config;


<mat-tab-group *ngIf="pcpConfig != undefined">
  <mat-tab label="Init Json"><app-init-json [eftForm]="configForm" [pcpConfig]="pcpConfig"></app-init-json></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Basic Parameters"><app-basic-parameters [eftForm]="configForm" [pcpConfig]="pcpConfig"></app-basic-parameters></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Aid list"><app-aid-list [tidId]="tidId"></app-aid-list></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Public keys"><app-public-keys [eftForm]="configForm"></app-public-keys></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

and in my nested component :

```
@Input('pcpConfig') pcpConfig: PayAppInitFileDTO;
console.log(this.pcpConfig);
```

Here this.pcpConfig is undefined

Comment: Did you try with async flag (pipe)?  f.e. pcpConfig | async

Comment: @AdrianSawicki I have tried it [pcpConfig]="pcpConfig | async" but when I console.log(this.pcpConfig) in the component it gives me undefined.

Comment: you can create a boolean  flag to check if you have fetched the data and then display the component. `<mat-tab-group *ngIf="dataLoaded">`

Comment: @hawks That's what *ngIf="pcpConfig != undefined" does it only isn't undefined when I fetched the data. But for some reason that did't work. I've tested it and the *ngIf is working correctly.

Comment: @C0mpl3x in the snippet you have put you are creating a object `public pcpConfig: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);` and `pcpConfig` will never be `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I will edit the code because with the update I'm not using BehaviorSubject.

Comment: Its weird. Can you try to put your condition like a truthy expression. `*ngIf="pcpConfig"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234907/discussion-between-c0mpl3x-and-hawks).

Comment: Basically Hawks solved your issue, so you should have given his comments an upvote (they were useful), like I did. And since the issue is a structural directive ngIf that doesn't get applied, maybe change the title in that direction. So that someone struggling with a similar issue, might find it (and also to prevent downvotes for this and future questions).

Comment: qqtf You are correct I upovoted hawkses comment and @hawks if you post the answer and I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding `*ngIf="pcpConfig"` to my mat-group so it doesn't load before the config.

Note:
Logging the value from constructor will return undefined, need to log from `ngOnInit` or somewhere else